# Putting an aged sites files on Amazon AWS (S3)

Tags: amazon-s3

For the last 6 or years, I've been running an online video hosting site.

Back then, hosting your content on services like S3 wasn't the biggie that  it is today, so everything is currently stored on our very expensive dedicated servers. The overages on data are much more expensive.

My question is this: What is the process of moving TB's of data on to a service like Amazon Aws where the site is all coded to link to files on our current server.

Editing hundreds-of-thousands of video links to point to the new Amazon AWS locations surely wouldn't be the ideal?

In this situation, is there a more "easy" approach to this dilemma.

All files are in a singular folder structure. IE; example.com/files/video.mp4

Would it possibly be more of a, leave the current files were they are and just have all future videos put on AWS?

I feel like I'm missing a piece of how this works as if for example IMGUR (who has trillions of images) wanted to move from AWS to another similar storage, it would be impossible to re-link trillions of links.

Any help is appreciated.